# I need to happen a process between 2 given times in Arduino

Tags: time, rtc

In my project i have a function which i only need to execute if the current time is between given 2 times. Note that the time is fetched from RTC so its 24hr. For example if current time is 23:00,start time is 20:00 and end time is 5:00 the function must execute and not execute otherwise.

```
if((fromhour>=now.hour() && fromminute>=now.minute()) || (tohour>=now.hour() && tominute>=now.minute()))
{
     //Call function
}
```

I tried this code but not working as expected. please give a solution for this problem.

Comment: convert now.time() hh, mm, ss into three separate bytes and do the comparison that way

Comment: How to compare. I need the if statement. Can you give me the code.